# Django: display a preview of an object's attribute - Class based views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Using a ListView Class-based-view, I am looping over the objects present in the database of a certain model in my HTML template, and, for instance, I can access an object's "body_text" attribute with the following syntax: `{{object.body_text}}`

What if I wanted to only show the first 20 characters of that "body_text" attribute in my HTML template?

How can I set that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st Method**

Use the truncatechars filter in your HTML template.Truncates a string if it is longer than the specified number of characters. Truncated strings will end with a translatable ellipsis character (“…”).

```
{{object.body_text|truncatechars:20}}
```

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#truncatechars

**2nd Method**

Use the slice filter in your HTML template.

```
{{object.body_text|slice:":20"}}
```

Referernce: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice

Answer (score 0):

Found it, eventually.

Use the `|slice:":"` filter in your HTML template.

For example, if you only want to display the first 10 characters of a given attribute, use:

```
{{object.body_text|slice:":10"}}
```